# Using Kendo Grid How to remove the column Borders?

Tags: javascript, css, telerik, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm using a Kendo UI Grid and by default I get column separator lines or a border line. (Vertical line down the column). How do you remove them.

Mark-up:

```
<div class="grid">
    <h3>Current<span class="goal-count">15</span></h3>
</div>
```

Here is a link to a JSFiddle project:  http://jsfiddle.net/mackry/RbmAz/

Any Suggestions?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is just a matter of changing the CSS to remove the border.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try defining the following style:

```
.k-grid td {
     border-width: 0;
}
```

*NOTE*: Remember that this style is defined in KendoUI CSS so you should define this the very last.